# Facebook "Like Box Embed" not working - On Developer Portal & beyond

Tags: facebook

When visiting the Facebook Developers site, for the "Like Box" feature... I am unable to get a particular Facebook URL to work.  https://www.facebook.com/laxonlark518 and http://www.facebook.com/laxonlark518   will not provide any "display" or "preview" on the Facebook Developers page (when it should), and when I try to use the code (regardless), it also won't display anything on my website.

Are there some internal Facebook settings for this Facebook Page that would prevent this "like box embedded code" from working?

Answer (score 0):

First question I will ask you is this, the URL, is it a Facebook Page or a personal Facebook account? I need to know this but let's keep it simple.

If your URL is a Facebook personal account, you won't be able to see any previews. On the contrary, if your URL is a Facebook page, you'll be able to see your required preview.

Use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/ to test and get your results and corresponding codes.